# Problem with tags list <li> inside a fixed width UL

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a small problem with a list of tags into a wordpress blog!

My list of tags are contained into a fixed width UL.

I would like to avoid word-wrap like for the tag "Human Resources"...

I would prefer that the entire tag goes on a second line.

[image]

I'm using the function the_tags like this :

```
<?php the_tags('<ul id="my-tags"><li class="cute-tag">','</li><li class="cute-tag">','</li></ul>'); ?>
```

My Css

```
#my-tags{
margin:0;
width:350px;
float:left;
}

#my-tags li {
display: inline;
font-family: Verdana, Arial,sans-serif;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size: 10px;
margin-right:5px;
font-weight:600;
padding:4px;
background:#2d0e0f;
list-style-type: none;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

#my-tags li  a{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:100;
font-style: normal;
}

#my-tags li  a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Cheers,

Jk_

Comment: if you provide a copy of the generated HTML, we could run a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem starts on your css definitions of the list..

i set up a corrected fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tobiasmay/72q9n/

after you corrected these, no-wrap should work.

Comment: Can you clarify which bits of his CSS were actually wrong? Its not that helpful an answer on its own considering that the fiddle has masses of changes that I am reasonably sure are not relevant.

Comment: It totally does the trick! I just added a float:left; to my LI element and a display:block; to my LI anchor... Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the tags from wrapping using a `white-space` css rule:

```
#my-tags li {
    ...
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**Update:**  I can't see any reason why the above wouldn't work, but have you tried applying the same to the anchor instead?

```
#my-tags li a {
    ...
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use a non-breaking space. Instead of "Human Resources", write "Humain&nbsp;Resources".

Comment: @Dexter : I already tried white-space:nowrap; but it does not make the trick... The li objects don't respect the width of the UL.
http://yfrog.com/b7screenshot20101119at134p

Comment: @gulbrandr : Same for the non-breaking space!

Comment: I suspect the margin and padding properties in '#my-tags li' to make the li objects to overflow the ul size.

Comment: @JK_ have you tried applying the style to the anchor (see update above)?

Comment: @Dexter : I tried applying it to the anchor too... but same result! If you want you can check it on www.msfb30.be login:contributor/pass:contributor